# Filesize changed after bcp export || Restoring Database isnt working [SQL, C#]

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, export, bcp

I am currently creating a table and filling it with a binary and a Name:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand commandAdd = new SqlCommand("CREATE TABLE dbo.tempTable (filename VARCHAR(100), blob VARBINARY(max));", conn);
conn.Open();

if (commandAdd.ExecuteNonQuery() != 0)
{
    byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileSource);
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.tempTable (blob,filename) values (@blob,@name)", conn);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("blob", fileBytes);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", dbName);
}
```

Then I try to Export it to a Location on the local hdd:

```
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery("xp_cmdshell 'bcp \"SELECT blob FROM " + dbName + ".dbo.tempTable\" queryout " + destinationPath + " -T -c'");
```

My Problem is that the file from the Export has a wrong size.

Original Size: 2069Kb
New Size: 4138Kb

It is always the original size * 2.

Another Problem is that restoring the database to SQL isnt working...
I think this is a Problem caused by the first Problem.

```
sqlConnectionString = "User ID=\"" + username + "\";pwd=\"" + pw + "\";Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=" + dataSource + ";";
using (SqlConnection masterConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
{
    masterConn.Open();
    SqlCommand masterCmd = masterConn.CreateCommand();
    masterCmd.CommandText = "RESTORE DATABASE " + dbName + " FROM DISK = '" + destinationPath + "'";
    masterCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Relax

Comment: It may not be exactly what you are looking for but have you thought of using FILESTREAM instead of BCP in order to export your data? There is an SO example on another thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21481221/export-blob-from-remote-sql-server-and-save-to-file-on-disk-where-sql-server-is/21481350#21481350

Comment: this is also my thread.. I've tried that but it's not the way we Need it in our Company.

Comment: How about creating a stored proc with the BCP code and appropriate params and then use c# to just call the stored proc? This way you can validate both the export and import of the BCP irrespective of the c# code?

Comment: Can you Show me a stored proc the way i Need it? Would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem was the missing of a Format File. BCP always added a prefix at the beginning of the file. Thats why the file was always corrupted.

Run this in cmd:

```
bcp [insertYourTableNameHereWithoutBrackets] format nul -S [insertYourServerNameHereWithoutBrackets] -T -n -f C:\Format.fmt
```

Then run the query in SQL Server:

```
xp_cmdshell 'BCP "[YourQueryHereWithoutBrackets]" queryout [YourDestinationPathWithoutBrackets] -T -f C:\Format.fmt'
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

please find the example of such SP below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [ExportBlobDataFromTable]

@columns varchar(500) = 'ID, BlobColumn, TextColumn', -- the columns used for the export, comma separated
@table varchar(500) = 'BlobTable', -- the table name used for the export
@outputFileName varchar(200) = 'C:\temp\extract.csv', -- fully_qualified_path_to_file
@bcpCommand varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN

SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT ' + @columns + ' FROM ' + @table + '" queryout "' ++@outputFileName + '" -T -n'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
END;
```

This will create the SP and you can call it from another window like this:

```
USE [test]
GO

DECLARE @columns varchar(500)
DECLARE @table varchar(500)
DECLARE @outputFileName varchar(200)
DECLARE @bcpCommand varchar(1000)

SET @columns = 'ID, BlobColumn, TextColumn';
SET @table  = 'BlobTable'; 
SET @outputFileName = 'C:\temp\extract.csv';

EXECUTE [dbo].[ExportBlobDataFromTable] 
  @columns
 ,@table
 ,@outputFileName
 ,@bcpCommand
GO
```

Or from your C# method:

```
 private void CallSpFromCode()
 {
     var sqlConnectionString = "User ID=\"" + username + "\";pwd=\"" + pw + "\";Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=" + dataSource + ";";
     using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString )) {
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ExplortBlobDataFromTable", con)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@columns", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "ID, BlobColumn,TextColumn";
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@table", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "BlobTable";

      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: No, this isnt working. Again the original size * 2 as outputsize. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: What happens if you try to import the data back to the database using BCP? If the data is fine, then I don't see an issue with the size, as long as the import is successful. Could you test that, using SQL only?

Comment: We've tested it. The import is failing because the file is invalid.

Comment: Sorry to come back to this but did you use the -n flag for exporting using native format?

Comment: I am using -T -c as flags.

Comment: I think that may be the problem. In my SP example above, I supplied -T -n as the flags and this is because you are not using a format file for your BCP. Can you try it again with -n and let me know how you get on?

Comment: It isnt working. "The media family on medium is invalid" - This is the same message we get with -T -c.

Comment: @Relax, I think we are tackling two separate problems here. Did you get that message on the backup/restore operation or the BCP export/import? If the error relates to sql backup/restore, it suggests that you have a corrupt backup. I would perform a manual SQL backup and restore to verify that the database is in order. If it originated from the bcp operation, then I will have to look into it

Comment: I got that message on the restore Operation. Restoring the database manually is working without Problems. If i try to restore a database that was created with the BCP Export it says invalid file.

Comment: A binary comparison revealed:
Backup from Database: TAPE[00][00][03]...
Database after BCP Export: [00]z&[00][00][00][00]TAPE[00]...

The size of the two database is now the same. (I think it was because of -n)